# Injecting hibernate session to Jersey using HK2

Tags: java, hibernate, dependency-injection, jersey-2.0, hk2

I'm developing little app and have some issues with DI.

I have a repository class for persisting my entities which I inject to my service. And I'd like to inject Session object to it using H2K.
For this purpose I try do something similar described in following SO posts:

1. [Jersey + HK2 + Grizzly: Proper way to inject EntityManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081840/jersey-hk2-grizzly-proper-way-to-inject-entitymanager)
2. [Using Jersey 2.0, how do you register a bindable instance per request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396165/using-jersey-2-0-how-do-you-register-a-bindable-instance-per-request)
3. [How do I properly configure an EntityManager in a jersey / hk2 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045019/how-do-i-properly-configure-an-entitymanager-in-a-jersey-hk2-application)

So I created SFFactory class and register it in ApplicationConfig.

*SFFactory.java*

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class SFFactory implements Factory<Session> {

private SessionFactory factory;

public SFFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder srBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
    srBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(srBuilder.build());
    }

@Override
public Session provide() {
    return factory.openSession();
    }

@Override
public void dispose(Session session) {
    if (session.isOpen()) {
        session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

*ApplicationConfig.java*

```
import org.alexdzot.phonettesttask.repository.MessageRepository;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/rest/*")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

public ApplicationConfig() {
    packages("org.alexdzot.phonettesttask");
    register(new AbstractBinder() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bindFactory(SFFactory.class).to(Session.class);
            bindFactory(MessageRepositoryFactory.class).to(MessageRepository.class).in(Singleton.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*DefaultMessageRepository*

```
import org.alexdzot.phonettesttask.model.Message;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class DefaultMessageRepository implements MessageRepository {

@Inject
private Session session;

public void saveMessage(Message message) {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(message);
        tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        } finally {
        session.close();
        }
    }

public List<Message> getAllMessages() {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    List<Message> messages = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        messages = session.createCriteria(Message.class).list();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        } finally {
        session.close();
        return messages;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the app and trying to call repository methods I get NullPoinerException. I can't understand what am I doing wrong.
This is what Tomcat log is saying:

```
*08-Aug-2015 02:42:18.232 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [org.alexdzot.phonettesttask.config.ApplicationConfig] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.alexdzot.phonettesttask.repository.DefaultMessageRepository.getAllMessages(DefaultMessageRepository.java:42)
    at org.alexdzot.phonettesttask.service.MessageResource.viewSentMessages(MessageResource.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:403)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)*
```

Any ideas what wrong with my solution and what causes that problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Main problem:**

> `[java.lang.NullPointerException]`

Look at your repository class

```
@Service
public class DefaultMessageRepository implements MessageRepository {

    @Inject
    private Session session; <-------------------+
                                                 | // You shadow session
    public void saveMessage(Message message) {   |
        Session session = null;   <--------------+
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

You are shadowing the injected field `session`. So you are just using the local `session`, which is null. So in your method, just get rid of `Session session = null;`. The injection should work fine, and you should be able to just use the `session` field.

**Another Problem:**

The same `Session` is being used for all request. Since `DefaultMessagFactory` is a singleton, HK2 asserts that `Session` should also be a singleton, since it is contained within a singleton. So instead of making the `SFFactory` the default `@PerLookup` scope, you get a factory that is a singleton, and so only one `Session` will be created. This is not the behavior you should want. You can test this by putting some print statements inside your factory class.

One way to make sure that a new `Session` is created for each request is to:

1. Use [`javax.inject.Provider<Session>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html), to lazily load the session, which will allow use to keep it in the scope we configured.

   ```
   @Inject
   private javax.inject.Provider<Session> session;

   @Override
   public void saveEvent(Event event) {
       Session s = session.get();
       Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
   ```
2. Configure the `SFFactory` in a request scope

   ```
   @Override
   protected void configure() {
       bindFactory(SFFactory.class)
               .to(Session.class)
               .in(RequestScoped.class);
   }
   ```

The other thing to fix is that `SessionFactory` should be a single instance through the application. For that we can create a single factory for it, and inject it into the `SFFactory`. For example

```
public class SessionFactoryFactory implements Factory<SessionFactory> {

    private final SessionFactory factory;

    public SessionFactoryFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder srBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        srBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(srBuilder.build());
        System.out.println("--- SessionFactory Created ---");
    }

    @Override
    public SessionFactory provide() {
        System.out.println("--- SessionFactory Provided ---");
        return factory;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(SessionFactory factory) {
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

The in your `SFFactory`

```
public class SFFactory implements Factory<Session> {

    private final SessionFactory factory;

    @Inject
    public SFFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    @Override
    public Session provide() {
        System.out.println("--- Session Created ---");
        return factory.openSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(Session session) {
        if (session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

You configuration would change to look like

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bindFactory(SessionFactoryFactory.class)
            .to(SessionFactory.class)
            .in(Singleton.class);
    bindFactory(SFFactory.class)
            .to(Session.class)
            .in(RequestScoped.class);
}
```

---

### UPDATE

So it seems aside from the shadowing, another main problem was in the `MessageRepositoryFactory` that the OP didn't show (in github project from comments).

```
public class MessageRepositoryFactory implements Factory<MessageRepository> {
    @Override
    public MessageRepository provider() {
        return new DefaultMessageRepository();
    }
    ...
}
```

When you instantiate the object your self, by default, the framework doesn't handle the injection. So that's why the injection of the `Session` didn't happen.

Instead of using the a `Factory` like this, you could simply bind like this

```
bind(DefaultMessageRepository.class).to(MessageRepository.class).in(..);
```

This way the framework creates the instance. The `Factory` should really only be used where it is not possible to bind the above way, for instance you have some initializations to do. We could have even not created the `Factory` for the `SessionFactoryFactory` and instead did all the session factory configuration elsewhere and just binded the instance. For example

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory =...
...
bind(sessionFactory).to(SessionFactory.class);
```

We just bind a `SessionFactory` singleton.

Comment: Thank you for you time and help! But when I did what you suggested I get the same result - NullPointerException.

Comment: What line (piece of code) is the NullPointerException pointing to? I've tested this and it works fine. Just removing the method local `Session session` declaration allows it to work fine. The request of this answer is an improvement. Dd you try it with just removing the Session declaration inside the method?

Comment: I added System.out.println() statements to SFFactroy and SessionFactoryFactory and it seems that provide method is never called.

Comment: Check that your Hibernate config is good (no exceptions). Test on a standalone main method. If all is good, Making the all the fixes mentioned above has been tested to work. I don't know what else to tell you from there. I removed the repository binding for brevity, but it should still be there. Maybe that's missing. I don't know

Comment: If I inject Provider to get Session inside repository it points to line with provider.get() . If I inject Session object directly it points to line where I call save() or create criteria for getting all results from database.

Comment: I did not remove repository binding. hibernate config file looks good. If I call utility class to get Session inside repository everything is OK.

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I will post a working project to github. I'm eating right now, so give me maybe 30 minutes

Comment: [Here's mine](https://github.com/psamsotha/stackoverflow-jersey-hibernate). I'll check your out a bit later.

Comment: Ahh I think I spot the problem. I didn't notice you were using a factory for the repository. When you instantiate the repository yourself, the injection doesn't occur. You don't need to factory, just use `bind(<repoimpl.clas>).to(<repoconract.class>).in(..)`. Notice It's not using your factory. You just let the framework create the instance

Comment: Thank you! That's was the real problem. Now everything works as I expect.

Comment: One thing I wasn't quite sure about during my testing was the fact that `dispose` is never called. I don't know if this leads to a resource leak or what. I just thought about it, reading one of the posts you linked to. You may want to do some profiling. Also maybe look into using `getCurrentSession` instead of `openSession` AFAIK, using `getCurrentSession` uses thread locals and you may not need to explicitly close them. I am not 100% sure. You may want to look into this further.